# Is there a general approach to enums within enums?

Tags: class, object, enums

*Disclaimer. I'm not sure if the title is the best one. I couldn't think of a better one that wasn't miles long. Please feel free to suggest an improvement.*

When a programmer is designing a set of states, it's natural to apply enumerations. In case of e.g. weekdays, it's obvious, traditionally accepted and straight-forward. However, sometimes, we also need to set the reason of the status as e.g. task management. We can have states as follows:

```
enum Status { New, Active, Inactive }
```

but still require to have a **status of the status**, a **stage of the status** or maybe a **reason of the status**. Normally, I'd add a bunch of new enumeration like so:

```
enum StatusOfNew { UnseenYet, RefusedToEvenLookAtAndOrQuitTheJob }
enum StatusOfActive { Assigned, Commenced, BeingTested }
enum StatusOfInactive { Done, Trashed, GivenUpOnBecausePeopleKeepQuittingTheJob }
```

An alternative approach would be to have a long list of all the combinations in the following way.

```
enum Status
{ 
  New_UnseenYet, New_RefusedToEvenLookAtAndOrQuitTheJob,
  Active_Assigned, Active_Commenced, Active_BeingTested,
  Inactive_Done, Inactive_Trashed, Inactive_GivenUpOnBecausePeopleKeepQuittingTheJob
}
```

Then, we have the classy approach, where each state is its own type with a common superclass and specific stages/reasons.

```
class New : Status
{
  enum Reason
  {
    UnseenYet,
    RefusedToEvenLookAtAndOrQuitTheJob
  }
}
```

I can wage them against each other considering the relation between complexity of implementation, cost of maintenance and gain in robustness. However, I wonder if there's other methods to consider, syntaxes to apply or approaches that void the problematic all together.

*Mainly, as a MS monkey I want to see a language specific solution in C#. However, being a curious and open-minded creature, I'd welcome suggestions from other lingos, as well. I've tried to ask this question on Programmers but, apparently, my questions are too dumb and the site told me to duck off (no profanity intended, the typo is intentional and I love ducks).*

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. This is really a *state* and a *reason*. But how your code gets at either should drive your design.

If you expect to have state model for both, then you might need nested enums. Otherwise, a class or class/enum configuration makes more sense.

The aim is to have readable, maintainable code. Enums are there for safety and readability. So the decision is one of appropriateness in context.

That is, there is no top down natural better. All your approaches are valid in the right context.

Comment: I totally agree with your point. And, as I mentioned, I do already evaluate the relation between complexity and gain. What I was most curious about if there were even more architectures to consider, that I might have missed.

Comment: I see. I admit I just read the beginning where the question seems to be asked and skimmed the implementations. Maybe pull your question out and place it at the top or bottom as part of a tl;dr section...

Comment: I have **very** mixed emotions now. On one hand I agree with your suggestion  pragmatically (to move out the actual question). On the other, I fell such a wave of #¤%& for classifying three, four short paragraphs as TL, hehe. Is it really a long post? Am I totally off thinking it's short and to-the-point?

Comment: I didn't say it was too long. I said the specific, germane question could have been posed in a more obvious place. I ended up answering the question in the title, not the one buried in a paragraph at the end. I'm sure others would have done the same.